# What flowering plants bloom between mid January and mid February on Honshu, Japan?

Tags: plant-recommendations, flowering, winter

I love Japan its for nature, plants (like [Nemophila](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nemophila) that bloom in spring at [Hitachi Seaside Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitachi_Seaside_Park)) and luxury fruits.

I would like to know what flowering plants I could expect to bloom between the dates of January 15 and February 10 on the island of Honshu in Japan, specifically in the areas near Osaka, Kyoto, Nagoya and Tokyo.

Comment: Hello Matthew.  Welcome.  Can you expand or explain in more detail what you mean by 'Japan has no nature or plants..'  Do you mean it has no plants in flowering during that time frame?

Comment: Today is February 4th. Are you already mostly done with your trip or is it still almost a year away?

Comment: @GardenGems yes! thx for filling in!

Comment: @stephie i'm asking for next year. i usually can get holiday time off just in chinese new year.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the following plants are normally blooming this time of the year.

- Prunus × subhirtella, thought to be a natural hybrid or a very old bred hybrid, from Japan.  The two most common cultivar of this are Prunus × subhirtella 'Autumnalis’ and the pink flowered Prunus × subhirtella ‘Autumnalis Rosea’ These beauties start blooming in fall and bloom through out winter.  They have a great fragrance which is only noticed on warm days.  [Winter Flowering Cherry](https://thestreettree.com/2018/03/04/winter-flowering-cherry-the-great-deceiver/)
- Mahonia x media that also bloom from fall through out winter.  There are a few different cultivars like the tall Mahonia x media 'Charity', Mahonia × media ‘Arthur Menzies’ & Mahnoia x media 'Winter Sun'.  [Mahonia x media](https://www.greatplantpicks.org/plantlists/saved_searches/13733)
- Hellebores, the early Hellebore niger should still be blooming and Hellebore orientalis may have started.  There are also other Hellebore species and hybrids.[Hellebore](https://www.homestratosphere.com/types-of-hellebore-flowers/)
- Witch hazel Hamamelis mollis & Hamamelis x intermedia both bloom in January and February.  [Hamamelis](https://www.greatplantpicks.org/plantlists/saved_searches/723)
- Skimmia japonica which is a winter blooming flower, popular varieties are 'Rubinetta', 'Rubella', & 'Fragrant Cloud'[Skimmia](https://www.gardenia.net/plant/skimmia-japonica-japanese-skimmia)
- Snowdrops [Snowdrops](https://www.greatplantpicks.org/plantlists/saved_searches/199)
- Flowering Plums Prunus × blireana & Prunus cerasifera may have begun to flower, depending on the winter.  Popular varieties include 'Thundercloud' and 'Pissardii' [Flowering Plums](https://homeguides.sfgate.com/flowering-plum-tree-40569.html)

Comment: Also camelia japonicas , which come in a great variety of colors and shapes.

Comment: Not Camelia japnonica (not yet), but Camelia sasanqua will be in full bloom with popular varieties like Yuletide & Apple Blossom

Comment: Hard to believe the growing seasons would be that different from zone 8 in US. When I was there many plantings looked to be in about the same season as here . My sasanquas start in Oct and go to the first of the year  . It is about mid Japonica season right now ( Feb.4) ; some finished , some mid season ( Debutante ) , and  some buds showing color and some buds tight and green. Maybe they have "wild" Japonicas that are different from varietals.

Comment: @blacksmith37  We would both be correct & incorrect.  When plants bloom is based on many things, how cold hardy a plant is not one of them.  Blooms are triggered by many things, the amount of light and heat are two of those.Hardiness zones do not play a part. Japan stretches from Latitude 20 up to Latitude 45, so yes part are getting good enough light to trigger Camellia japonica, where other parts are not.  Some are maybe getting the heat levels, but I would suspect much of it does not have the warmth needed to trigger C.j.. Like Cam. sa. is currrently blooming the northern PNW, but not C.j.

Answer (score 0):

My friend got back last week from Japan - his photos show only evergreens and bare branches. No flowers. Also Rain and Snow.